# Firebase PERMISSION_DENIED push notifications without database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am working with Firebase in order to use "push notifications" in my web application. And it launches this error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied ; Zone:  ; Task: WebSocket.addEventListener:message ; Value: Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

I have read that it seems an error related with the database permission denied. And it solves changing the write and read permissions. But in my case I don't have database in firebase.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

My code bellow:

```
const userId = 'user001';
this.messagingService.requestPermission(userId);
this.messagingService.receiveMessage();
this.message = this.messagingService.currentMessage;
```

When I requested permission I do the token update based on userId to Firebase DB. Maybe in my case is not necesary to do this?(I don't use right now database) How can I replace this?

```
 requestPermission(userId) {
    this.messaging.requestPermission()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('notification permission granted.');
        return firebase.messaging().getToken();
      })
      .then(token => {
        console.log(token);
        this.updateToken(userId, token);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      });
  }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you add the code that is causing this error?

Comment: thanks André, I have updated my post with the code bellow.